# definition of derived algebra $[L,L]$ of a Lie algebra $L$

Tags: definition, lie-algebras

Definition of derived algebra of a Lie algebra $L$ is given by linear span of commutators $[x,y]$ for $x,y \in L$. but here why do we take linear span and why cant we just consider collection of all commutators alone which for few examples it seems they are itself forming a sub algebra. please explain me the impotence of taking linear span.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you already know why.

Comment: @anon I cant see why this is true that much obviously. can you tell some examples of Lie algebra to verify this?

Comment: The very fact that it isn't in any way obvious that the set of commutators is closed under addition is **itself** the answer to your question. If you wanted to ask the slightly different (better) question, "what are examples of lie algebras with bracket given by commutator whose set of commutators is not closed under addition," that's what you should do! (The first thing that comes to mind is the sum $[A,B]+[C,D]\in k\langle A,B,C,D\rangle$, but I don't know how to prove it isn't a commutator.)